# Using kernel debug symbols on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, linux, kernel, qemu, debug

I see that I can install packages that contain the kernel debug symbols in Ubuntu as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197016/how-to-install-a-package-that-contains-ubuntu-kernel-debug-symbols). Is it possible to do the same for Raspberry pi? I'd really like to have kernel symbols for the raspbian that I'm running in QEMU.